# Underline in attributed text not working in iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, nsattributedstring

I want to create a method that returns me attributed text.

here is the code that i am using

```
- (NSAttributedString *)getUnderlineAttributedStringForText:(NSString *)strWholeString andTextToHaveLink:(NSString *)strLink TextColor:(UIColor *)textColor LinkColor:(UIColor *)linkColor withFont:(UIFont*)font {

NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, strWholeString.length);
NSRange linkRange = [strWholeString rangeOfString:strLink];
NSLog(@"String Link :: %@",[strWholeString substringWithRange:linkRange]);
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strWholeString];
// Paragraph Style
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrapStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.new;
paragrapStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrapStyle range:stringRange];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:textColor range:stringRange];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:stringRange];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:linkRange];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:linkColor range:linkRange];

return attributedString;
}

// This is how I call the method 
[btnTermOfUse setAttributedTitle:[self getUnderlineAttributedStringForText:@"By signing up you agree to the Terms of Use" andTextToHaveLink:@"Terms of Use" TextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] LinkColor:[UIColor orangeColor] withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This code works fine in all device except 6+.

**Edits**
- in 6+ just underline is not showing text colour change for the link text.
[image: in 6+ just underline is not showing text colour change for the link text]
I can see the underline in iPhone 6 or 5S.

Any one have any idea regarding this?

I know there are already so many questions related to this but they didn't help me so I am writing here.

Comment: So what is the problem with 6+?

Comment: please check out my edits

Comment: Also on the simulator or just on the device? It works just fine on the simulator here.

Comment: I tried to run on both Device and Simulator but get the same result

Comment: Now it's working on simulator but still not on device

Comment: @Eiko, this isn't working on iPhone6+ device but works fine here in simulator too. Possible bug by Apple?

Comment: Will check this on my 6+ soon. But what did you change? Did you use the exact code you posted? We need 1 to 1 copy here... (and at least the color is wrong). Although the name of method is ugly and nonconforming to standards, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Eiko, see my answer. I found an ugly hack !!

Comment: Posted code works on my 6+ without problems. I think your hack might just "fix" another problem, maybe the constraints are off and the button is too small etc.

Answer (score 2):

Found a hack !! :(

you should write this line before setting up the text,

```
[btnTermOfUse titleLabel].numberOfLines = 0;
```

This will show you the line on device too.